# Dexguard implemenation

Tags: dexguard

Hi getting the below error with dexguard and I have also excluded the android.support.v7.app in rule

java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate: void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.() failed to verify: void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.(): [0x0] Constructor returning without calling superclass constructor (declaration of 'android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate' appears in /data/app/com.intradiem.agentmobile-nzRaODeKWvj81AKePijb-A==/base.apk)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(:525)
        at com.intradiem.agentmobile.IntradiemApplication.(:27)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1102)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:983)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5715)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with the -assumenosideeffects rule.
Ensure that you do not use wildcards in combination with this rule, like that:

```
-assumenosideeffects class XXX {
    *;
}
```

This will also remove calls to the superclass constructors as you experience it.